# Does anyone know how I can only submit when my regex is correct?

Tags: php, mysql, regex, submit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Regular expression wont produce error echo, could anyone please help me?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12218821/regular-expression-wont-produce-error-echo-could-anyone-please-help-me)

Does anyone know how to prevent form data from inserting into database when regular expressions are incorrect. Is there maybe some way to disable the button with php (already did that with javascript).

```
 function ValidateForm($string, $type){

    switch($type)
        {
        case 'name':
            $pattern="/^[A-Za-z. -]+$/";
            break;
        case 'sex':
            $pattern="/[MWmw]/";
            break;
        case 'insertion':
            $pattern="/^[A-Za-z]*$/";
            break;
        case 'initials':
            $pattern="/^([A-Z]\.)+$/";
        break;
        case 'adress':
            $pattern="/^([A-Za-z -])+[0-9]+([a-z -])*$/";
            break;
        case 'postcode':
            $pattern="/^[1-9][0-9]{3}[]?[A-Za-z]{2}$/";
            break;
        case 'phone':
            $pattern="/^[0-9]{10}$/";
            break;
        case 'email':
            $pattern="/(^[0-9a-zA-Z_\.-]{1,}@([0-9a-zA-Z_\-]{1,}\.)+[0-9a-zA-Z_\-]{2,}$)/";
            break;
        case 'postbus':
            $pattern="/^[A-Z][a-zA-Z -]+$/";
            break;
        }



        if (preg_match($pattern, $string)){
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }   
        }   



        if (ValidateForm($_POST["surname"],'name')){
            $error1 = false; 
        }else{
            $error1 = true; 
        } 

        if (ValidateForm($_POST["sex"],'sex')){
            $error2 = false; 
        }else{
            $error2 = true; 
        }





                if (ValidateForm($_POST["insertion"],'insertion')){
            $error3 = false;
        }else{
            $error3 = true; 
        }

        if (ValidateForm($_POST["initials"],'initials')){
            $error4 = false;
        }else{
            $error4 = true; 
        }

        if (ValidateForm($_POST["name"],'name')){
            $error5 = false;
        }else{
            $error5 = true; 
        }


        if (ValidateForm($_POST["adress"],'adress')){
            $error6 = false;
        }else{
            $error6 = true; 
        }

        if (ValidateForm($_POST["postcode"],'postcode')){
            $error7 = false;
        }else{
            $error7 = true; 
        }           

        if (ValidateForm($_POST["postbus"],'postbus')){
            $error8 = false;
        }else{
            $error8 = true; 
        }

        if (ValidateForm($_POST["private_phone"],'phone')){
            $error9 = false;
        }else{
            $error9 = true; 
        }

        if (ValidateForm($_POST["mobile_phone"],'phone')){
            $error10 = false;
        }else{
            $error10 = true; 
        }

        if (ValidateForm($_POST["work_phone"],'phone')){

            $error11 = false;

        }else{
            $error11 = true;
        }

        if (ValidateForm($_POST["work_email"],'email')){
            $error12 = false;
        }else{
            $error12 = true;
        }

        if (ValidateForm($_POST["private_email"],'email')){
            $error13 = false;
        }else{
            $error13 = true;
    }
```

Comment: Didn't you have error display in your [previous post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12218821/regular-expression-wont-produce-error-echo-could-anyone-please-help-me)? What's not working about it? You might use Javascript, as you have, or HTML5 `pattern=` attributes for client-side **pre**-validation. Also using a form handler class might be advisable to reduce some of your repetetive code.

Comment: Are you doing anything with your `$errorXX` variables? Have you considered an array instead?` Might make sense for the name=>regex list as well.

Comment: This line `if (ValidateForm($_POST["surname"],'name')){
` and any below will never execute. move it out of the function

Comment: Why is there code after the returntrue;returnfalse; part? It won't get executed.

Comment: why cant the code cant get ecxuted  below the return true/false part?

Comment: Please disable the cut+paste keys on your keyboard when programming. This entire block of code only needs to be 15-20 lines long.

Answer (score 0):

Simple, use stored procedures instead. You just CALL them and let mysql core do the work for you.The procedures will return a boolean value if the regular expression was or was not matched.

Using mysql regular expression REGEXP : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `SP_REGEXP`(IN `Str` CHAR(32), OUT `result` INT)
        LANGUAGE SQL
        NOT DETERMINISTIC
        CONTAINS SQL
        SQL SECURITY DEFINER
        COMMENT ''
BEGIN
   DECLARE  result INT DEFAULT 0;
   SELECT str REGEXP '^[a-d]' INTO result;
END
```